# finding the last reading from a data.frame for ggplot2 using R

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to plot the price of vehicles over time. I'd like to include the reg. no of the vehicle as a marker for a sparkline. My data looks like this:

```
> head (x[c(1,2,3,4)])
   samp.date      idx price  reg.date
1 2012-11-15  xxxxxxb  27490  2010-3-1
2 2012-11-15  yyyyxxm  28990  2010-9-1
3 2012-11-15  zzzzzxxv 25980  2010-9-1
4 2012-11-15  aaaaaz   31995  2011-1-1
5 2012-11-15  aaaaaar  33995  2011-3-1
6 2012-11-15  aaaaxxc  30980  2011-3-1
```

For any given idx, there may be many sample dates (samp.date), the price may go up as well as down. So, I think that I'd like to use the last sample date and the price at that sample date (+/- some fudge factor) to label the ggplot lines, using geom_text.  However, I cannot seem to pull out the right coordinates.  I think that ddply (from plyr) is the right tool to use and I think that I'm making some progress:

```
ddply (x, .(idx), function (x) { return (c(tail(x$samp.date, 1), as.numeric (tail (x$price, 1))))})
```

but this coerces the x$price values to dates:

```
          idx         V1         V2
 1    aaaaaau 2013-05-19 2082-03-24
 2    abbbbbb 2013-05-19 2082-03-24
 3    accccco 2013-03-17 2054-11-06
 4    adddddo 2013-05-19 2068-07-15
```

It may be that I can use V2 as the y coordinate, but I'd feel happier if it were a number, rather than a date.  Is the issue that the function to ddply must return a matrix, rather than a data.frame? If so, how do I get different classes for the different dimensions returned?

Can I get different types / classes returned like this, or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in `ddply` may return a data frame.  In fact, it is the recommended practice:

```
ddply(x, .(idx), function (x) { 
        data.frame(date=tail(x$samp.date, 1),
                   price=as.numeric(tail(x$price, 1)))
      })
```

Comment: thanks, Noam. I'm not sure whether it's me, but I do find R very awkward as a programming language. If ddply is supposed to return a df, then why does it not coerce the return from the function into a df?

Comment: According to `ddply`'s documentation, "The most unambiguous behaviour is achieved when .fun returns a data frame - in that case pieces will be combined with rbind.fill. If .fun returns an atomic vector of fixed length, it will be rbinded together and converted to a data frame. Any other values will result in an error."  So it does coerce the output to a data frame, but only after all the outputs are combined.